# CSS Media Queries ADDING SCROLLBAR

Tags: html, css, web

i am trying to create a webpage that will use Media Queries to be responsive , i dont understand the concept that i have found about media queries absolutely ... but basicaly lets imagine that we have a basic website with some images and buttons i have seen some examples of using media queries , one of them is that we can detect resolution and if its smaller as for example min-width: 480px then we can use different css file or so , it means we have to rewrite the whole webpage 10 times in different layout , cant we just do that if the smaller resolution is detected then it will just add scrollbars ? so the webpage wont move its components but if the resolution gets smaller it will just add scrollbars , i have also seen code for it it uses overflow-x and same for y but it doesnot work for me

```
 @media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
        body {
           /*CODE GOES HERE*/
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Of course you can.

You can use the media query with `max-width` to detect those particular cases with small screens and add the scrollbar.

All the CSS outside will be used in both cases (bigger and smaller widths).

```
.class1{}
.class2{}
...
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    body {
       overflow-y: scroll;
    }
}
```

Comment: i have added it into my css file and it doesnot work i have resized the browser window to minimum and there is no scrollbar

Comment: That's the correct way to do it but I've been trying it in my browsers and the behavior changes in each one.

In Chrome, the scrollbar appears, even when you don't have enough content to scroll (but in this case, the bar it is empty).

In Firefox, the scrollbar is only visible when there is enough content to overflow the container.

Comment: Please let me know if it still doesn't work for you and I'll try to help you.